# Traduzione della frase inglese "To make a big deal (out of something)"

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Buongiorno,

Ho cercato "to make a big deal" nel dizionario e ho trovato:

> **To make a big deal out of something:**
>   
> fare un sacco di storie per qualcosa

Secondo me questa traduzione non è molto buona. Io pensavo

> parlare di qualcosa come se fosse una grande cosa

Cosa ne pensate? Si può tradurlo meglio?

Comment: Qual è “il dizionario”? Ce ne sono tanti diversi, a questo mondo, alcuni migliori, alcuni peggiori.

Comment: Dipende da quello di cui stai parlando: distinguere tra espressioni con diverse sfumature di significato senza una frase e un contesto preciso è impossibile.

Comment: Per completare il commento di Federico Poloni, la traduzione indicata può essere molto valida, ma dipende dal contesto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ho trovato diverse discussioni su Wordreference (metto i link alla fine) secondo cui questa espressione può avere traduzioni leggermente diverse anche a seconda del contesto in cui viene usata; la tua traduzione in generale mi sembra corretta.

Esistono diversi modi di dire che esprimono lo stesso concetto come: "farne un dramma" / "farne un affare di Stato"; un'altra traduzione che mi sembra corretta è "ingigantire qualcosa".

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/made-a-big-deal-over-you.2434296/
http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dont-make-a-big-deal.126667/
http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/big-deal.122300/

Answer (score 8):

Solitamente "Don't make a big deal" si può tradurre con "Non farne un dramma" o "Non farne un affare di stato"

Answer (score 4):

Ho trovato questa interessante spiegazione del significato di ***[to make a big deal (out of something)](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/make-a-big-deal-out-of-something)***

Quando dici che qualcosa "***is a big deal***" significa che ciò è importante per te. Ma quando tu dici "***make a big deal out of ___***", significa che quel qualcosa non è così importante ma tu ti comporti come se lo fosse.

Puoi usare ad esempio questa frase nelle seguenti situazioni:

Quando un membro della tua famiglia sta organizzando una grande festa per il tuo compleanno, anche se a te non te ne importa niente.

Quando qualcuno si arrabbia per una cosa che tu pensi essere solo un errore trascurabile.

Quando tu presti un po' di soldi a qualcuno e lui ti ringrazia in modo pedante ed eccessivo.

La frase "***make a big deal out of something***" è spesso usata nel cosiddetto ***[casual speech](http://www.phrasemix.com/concepts/casual-speech)***, cioè un modo di parlare che di solito usi con persone di fiducia molto vicine a te, come famigliari e amici, che fa largo uso di contrazioni, slang e grammatica semplificata.

Io tradurrei (oltre che **non farne un dramma** e **non farne una questione di stato** già suggerite) **non fare tutto questo rumore per nulla**, oppure **non farne una questione di vita o di morte**.

Comment: E in italiano quindi come lo diresti, che era quello che chiedeva l'OP?